# "Status: Failur-I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property." SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got the error while setting up SQL Developer to connect SQL Server.

SQL Developer Error:

> "Status: Failur-I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded.
>   Check the java.library.path system property."

I have applied all the below solutions but no luck, getting the same error again & again.

1) Download and open the JTDS folder.

2) The ntlmauth.dll you will find inside the x86/SSO folder.

3) The JtdsXA.dll you will find inside the x86/XA folder

4) Put the "ntlmauth.dll" and "JtdsXA.dll" inside the path SqlDeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin

5) Copy the jtds-1.3.1.jar to Sql Developer/sqldeveloper/lib

6) Reinstall Java as well

7) Restarted the system and SQL Developer number of times.

I am using SQL Developer 18.4 version.I am trying to connect through Windows authentication approach.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Isn't SQL Developer for Oracle only?

Comment: we can use it for both.